Using Django Debug Toolbar With DRF, Simple JWT Auth
django-debug-toolbar needs its output to be html, but i am using apis with jwt authentication (djangorestframework-simplejwt). So i am unable to use debug toolbar.
I have all the settings of IPs, Middlewares everything correct as per documentation.
All my APIs have Authentication and Authorization.
All my libraries, modules are in latest versions.
I have tried these methods

Using django spectacular and creating an Swagger Documentation for my APIs, but it is not generating correct documentation (my apis work on many models, so unable to generate correct schema), Many Schemas are missing and also i dont know why extend_schema is not working.
Used django-debug-panel by changing the errors with views.py, urls.py, middleware.py in django-debug-panel and also installed the chrome extension but i dont understand how to use it.
Used django-silk but i want to use debug toolbar.

Is there anyway i can use django debug toolbar somehow? I want to try again with any new ideas or changing anything in those methods i mentioned
Edit: Found a small tweak. Made a view which renders empty html and now it shows debug toolbar. Move to History Panel and there all the information of previous queries can be found.
If there is any other solution, please comment
